# Why is my foreach loop returning an extra index position?

Tags: php

I am pulling text from a .txt, I explode the line then re-explode it so it can be stored as an array. When I print_r after the 2nd explode it outputs an array with a 4th index position when it should only have 0 1 2 3. Any ideas why?
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

PHP

```
 list($title, $author, $publisher, $isbn) = explode('*', $line);

    print_r($line); //outputs a string


    $books = explode('*', $line);
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($books); //outputs array with extra index position.
```

Sample of Output

```
Array ( [0] => Business 101 [1] => John Smith[2] => 2002-07-18 [3] => 1-444-2589-x [4] => )
```

Sample of line from .txt file

```
Business 101*John Smith*2002-07-18*1-444-2589-x*
```

Comment: Is there a trailing `*` in `$line`?

Comment: yes there is an * at the very end of the line in the text file. Why?

Comment: When you explode it produces **all** the strings outside the delimiters so in this case it sees an empty string following the last `*` which it returns into the array.

Comment: What you acutally try to do is implementing an own file format. This is not recommended. Could you serve an example of a line?

Answer (score 1):

Please, share the content of **$line**, so I can try to help you.

I imagine just one explanation: $line have more values that you expect.

This is comprehensive if you import the data from a file (for example, a CSV file).

So, check if there's something like this:

```
BookName*Author*PublishDate*ISBN*
```

Have you seen the last *? This is the problem.

Explode function read the last * and create another field in the array.

If you want to fix this, you can remove the last *, or just pass a limit to your explode function (3 is the number, try it).

```
array explode(string $delimiter, string $string, int $limit);
```

Hope it helps you.

Best regards.

Comment: I tried entering a 3 in the limit and got an error.